# WebBrowser Control not showing PDF anymore

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser

Googled really much on this issue, but didnt find any related problems.

I wrote a Browser with WinForms and the webbrowser control and since a week ago the Browser is showing a little Icon on the top left corner with an "x" in it instead of PDF File on every Website.

Dont know why, cause it worked fine for a couple of months.

Also tried to change back to the IE9 Engine by setting the registry entries, cause i thought about some IE Updates. But didnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work in IE standalone? If not, then this question is off-topic and better asked on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: Yes of course its working. Also with IE without Addons. Adobe Addon will be activated but i deactivate it manually its also working without any PDF Addons running. Really strange how this is working...

Comment: Neither IE nor WebBrowser are capable of displaying a pdf by themselves, they display html.  An extension is required.  You didn't document which one you use but whatever you have sounds borken.  Which good odds that it is Adobe Reader, a program that manages to get significantly worse with each (frequent) release.  Unwise to depend on it.  There are many alternatives to displaying pdf, you need to go shopping.

Comment: But why has it shown the PDFs correct for so long time. And why is it possible with IE. Please try it yourself, start IE without Addons and browse to an online PDF. Then make sure the Adobe Addons are really disabled. IE will show you the PDF anyway... Why?

Comment: Ok i think i have found the answer, but can only post it in 4 hours because i have less reputation.... little bit weird this system...

Comment: @Floeee : You should contribute more ;-)

Comment: Yes :D but im not thaat experienced until now in all of those special questions out there.

Comment: PDF is activated as ActivX document, which is not considered an addon by IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the source of the problem. The trick is to build a x86 application. If you set any cpu or x64 platform in your build settings, this little box with the "x" will show up when you try to view PDFs.

But really dont know why this happens and why he can find addons from IE in the webbrowser control, cause i didnt use any one of them in my code and im also not using any dlls for this. And why IE is showing PDFs without Addons activated.

But its working again now.